# How do I change the default directory where GitBash opens?

Tags: windows-10, git-bash, start

I'm using GitBash on Windows 10.  Following some instructions online, I tried changing the directory where GitBash opens by updating the "Start in" field in the Properties' shortcut tab to be

```
%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Documents\projects
```

However, when I open GitBash, and enter "pwd" as soon as it opens, I keep seeing the current directory as

```
/c/Users/MYUSERID
```

What is the proper way to change the starting path of where GitBash opens?

Comment: Alternative (and maybe the cause): https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140603

Answer (score 0):

What you did is correct, except probably that in Properties you have
not removed from the Target field the parameter `--cd-to-home`
which overrides the "Start in" field and sets it back to
`%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`.

For more information see the post
[How do I change the default location for Git Bash on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671461/how-do-i-change-the-default-location-for-git-bash-on-windows)

Comment: I removed that param from the Target field and fired up GitBash once again.  Unfortunately, this didn't change anything.

Comment: What does the Target field looks like now? You could try also the other methods in the linked post.

Comment: The target field reads "C:\Users\myuserid\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\git-bash.exe"

Comment: You mean that there are no more parameters on the git-bash call? Look also at the other answers in my link and also examine your `gitconfig` file.

Comment: Correct there are no other parameters/arguments.  Any specific answer you are referring to?  That link has quite a few.